# Trash scheduling model for AMPL

Tags: scheduling, job-scheduling, ampl, operations-research

I have been working on a grabage collection problem in AMPL and these are the data:

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fTvE.png)

[Schedule and Garbage Collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FFw.png)

Obj fun : minimize total operational costs

Constraints :

1. Each shift should not work for more that 8 hrs
2. The garbge collected per shift is not more than 500 tons
3. On sundays, only
   - 4 dump trucks
   - 7 compactor truck
   - 8 mini dump truck

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fTvE.png)

[Schedule and Garbage Collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FFw.png)

Can anyone help me with this problem and how it can be formulated? especially with the data? Thank you!

Comment: How far have you gotten with it so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: thank you so much for replying sir

Comment: Good day, Mr. Brent please open the link provided. [link]  (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tLfW3QlI6SMUEZ9PSia5PEvKNM5G_KNqd5aulj02qf8/edit)

Comment: Please add any necessary information to your post here - the aim here is to produce questions and answers that don't depend overly on specific links. StackExchange is best suited to answering specific questions ("why is this code returning a float when I was expecting an int?") rather than general "how do I solve this problem" questions - I'd suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions to get an idea of how to write a clear question that we can help with.

Comment: Sorry sir, let me restate my question. I already tried to run my data and im stuck with the results in my console it shows that all my results are 0. 
1. "Is it normal for branch-and-bound nodes to be 0? what does it mean if it says 0?
2. If it says "no basis" in the console, what does it mean?

Comment: If the results are all zero, it probably means either that you're missing a constraint (so the cheapest solution is simply not to collect any garbage) or that the model didn't solve for some reason (AMPL variables default to zero until the solver or some other process overwrites them). Check your log.